# excel 2007 memory limit

Tags: excel, memory, limit

I would like to ask is there really no limit to the memory used by Excel 2007?

The microsoft specification says There's no limit

and I would like to verify it, but yet I Fail

My testing environment is: Windows7 64Bit, 4G Ram, not much memory in use

Here's what I have tried,

Create large integer array.  This could only use 1G Ram. FAIL-->PROMPT OOM Error
Create large string array, insert 1000 length string , uses 1.9G Ram. FAIL --> PROMPT OUT OF STRING SPACE

Create 1Million * 10 Columns data in a worksheet, keep duplicating it.   Uses 1.9G Ram. FAIL --> Prompt some random error.

My Question is, is there really no memory limit or I have really used up all the free memory on my pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel memory limits vary by version. Excel 2007 is limited to a theoretical 2 Gigabytes of virtual memory, but in practical terms is often not able to use as much of that because of memory fragmentation problems etc.
See http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm for some more details.

Comment: Thanks, I only remember my OS is 64Bit, but forget Excel only has 64bit version breaking the limit at version 2010. Excel 2007 only has 32bit version

Answer (score 0):

To find out how much memory is available to VBA copy/paste the code below and call `availableMemoryInMB()`

```
Function allocateMB(intNumMB As Integer) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim a As Variant
    ReDim a(intNumMB, 256, 256) As Variant 'intNumMB x 256 x 256 x 16 bytes = intNumMB MB
    allocateMB = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear
    Erase a
End Function

Function availableMemoryInMB() As Integer
    Dim intLow As Integer, intHigh As Integer, intTest As Integer
    intTest = 1: intHigh = 0
    Do
        If allocateMB(intTest) Then
            intLow = intTest
            If intHigh = 0 Then
                intTest = intTest * 2
            Else
                intTest = (intLow + intHigh) / 2
            End If
        Else
            intHigh = intTest
            intTest = (intLow + intHigh) / 2
        End If
    Loop Until intHigh - intLow <= 1 And intHigh > 0
    availableMemoryInMB = intLow
End Function
```

Execution of the code takes 2-20 seconds. In the 64 bit Excel versions several GB of memory are available to VBA, while in the 32 bit versions of Excel roughly half a GB is available.